# Pixel dimensions in TCPDF aren't correct

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

probably this has already been asked before but I can't get it working. I'm trying to use TCPDF to generate a PDF document which should have a rectangle of 10 pixels at the coordinates (0, 0). The code is the following:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 0);

$pdf->Cell(0, 2.645833333, '', 0, 1, '', true);
```

The rectangle is printed, but it has the wrong height in pixels. Default values for the TCPDF is to use the mm unit. I converted 10 pixels to mm using the website unitconversion.org. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

PDF's don't have pixels. They have points, how many, that depends on DPI (dots per inch). If you assume one point = one pixel, you can go from there and convert 10 points through 72 DPI (the default) to milimeters.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. I decided to go with pt as user unit. I then converted 10 pixels to points (7.5) but I still don't see the correct height. I suspect there is the SetImageScale which could potentially have a wrong value

Answer (score 1):

Its worth checking in tcpdf_config.php and the `PDF_UNIT` which can be one of `[pt=point, mm=millimeter, cm=centimeter, in=inch]`